# "I am the same <noun> as you are" - better way of putting it

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I want to say

> "I am same parent as you are, so I also have the right to demand what
> is best for my children",

but I am bothered by

> "I am same parent as you are"

because it looks like this phrase would mean that the person I am talking to is me. Is there a better way then to express my thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you’re looking for is “(just) as much a [noun] as”:

- I am (just) as much a parent as you (are).

But since you’re parenting the *same* kids:

- I am (just) as much **their** parent as you (are).

The “just” isn’t required, but it adds a sense of indignation, such as during an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly the phrase I was looking for. BTW, in my example I was not parenting same kids; I was talking to a parent of other kids, but that parent was a member of the same group of parents, except for some reason he thought that only he had the right to demand.